# Finding constant to satisfy convergence of infinite series using MacLaurin expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Given the following infinite series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n - \frac{eb}{n}$

find the constant b for which it converges.

My approach thus far has been to get $a_n$ on the form $\frac{c}{n^\alpha} + O(\frac{1}{n^\beta})$ with $\beta > \alpha$, i.e. finding a representation that is easier to work with and lends itself to comparison tests. More specifically, if I could get $a_n = \frac{c}{n} + O(1/n^2)$ with $c = 0$

I would be done, since then

$b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = m \neq 0$

I struggle with creating this easier representation.

$(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = e^{n ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}$

Then, possibly a MacLaurin-expansion for $ln(1+x)$, repeat the process for $e^x$ and then simplify... Here, my approach breaks down in very messy calculations.

Is this the correct approach to exercises like this one? How would I go about actually implementing the steps outlined above? Very thankful for any help.

Comment: The approach is right, but if you break down in very messy calculations, the execution is not optimal. Some hints: a) $e^{1 + u} = e \cdot e^{u}$, b) in the argument of the exponential, you need not go beyond $O(1/n^2)$ terms.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer, worked out in the end. A really good exercise for me to realise that knowing where something is likely to go saves time. If I want a certain result, namely $O(1/n^2)$, there's no reason to go beyond this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $$a_n=e -  \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n- \frac{eb}{n}$$ For large $n$, you have
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e-\frac{e}{2 n}+\frac{11 e}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ making
$$a_n=\frac{\frac{e}{2}-e b}{n}-\frac{11 e}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ and the harmonic series does not converge. Then, ???